# Модальное окно с Promise на vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, promise

Всем привет.

Как можно сделать модальное окно с *Promise* без применений различных фреймворков?

В интернете, за несколько дней, так и не смог найти адекватного примера. *(Все примеры на различных bootstrap и иже с ними. Для моего маленького, домашнего, проекта это лишнее.)*

Задача простая:

- по нажатию кнопки отрабатывает логика, часть которой - "вызов" окна с полем ввода (и своей внутренней логикой) и двумя кнопками - "ok & cancel";
- необходимо в том же куске кода обратно получить результат ввода.

Сейчас все реализовано через *callback* но там творится **hell**, хотелось бы на промисах.

С самими промисами немного знаком - ajax запросы на них.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: так переделай callback'и на Promise и все

Comment: любую асинхронную функцию с callback можно легко переделать в Promise: `new Promise(r=>func((...args)=>{ r(...args);}))` плюс вариации с передачей параметров. если конечно у тебя сейчас не половина Promise о которых ты не знаешь.

Comment: Вся необходимая информация должна быть непосредственно в вопросе. Лучше всего чтобы был [mcve]

Comment: Никто и не говорил про оборачивание класса. Нужно оборачивать только вызов функции

Comment: Очевидно недостаточно. Непонятно что у тебя есть, что ты хочешь получить. На вопрос в текущей постановке вполне отвечает мой первый комментарий. Собственно вся проблема как раз в том, что тебе _кажется_, что информации достаточно

Comment: Если ты не хочешь получить ответ, зачем задаешь вопрос? Сам же говоришь, что _Банально, просто, гуглинг на тему "js popup promise" показывает именно то, о чем я спрашиваю_ - добавь в запрос _чистый js_ и будет тебе счастье, возможно :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
// Модальное окно
class popup {
    constructor() {
        this._resolve;
        this._reject;
    }
    show() {

        ...<div><button id='no' type="button">No</button><button id='ok' type="button">Ok</button></div>...

        ok.addEventListener("click", function ok() { this._resolve(); }, false);
        no.addEventListener("click", function no() { this._reject(); }, false);

        document.body.appendChild(div);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._resolve = resolve;
            this._reject = reject;
        });
    }
}

// 2. Вызов
(async () => {
    try {
        let result = await new popup().show();
        ...
    } catch(e) {
        ...
    }
})();
```